# Finding a Seirawan game

Tags: famous-games

I am looking for a game played by Seirawan. I remember in the position that Black was heading for a Botvinnik formation(c5 and e5 but without d6 yet), and White had sacrificed a knight on e5 for an attack. I am 80% sure that Seirawan was Black.

Comment: Do you mean the pawn structure with c5-d6-e5? Or are you referring to the Semi-slav variation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this one:

```
[FEN ""]
[Site "it"]
[Date "1993.??.??"]
[Round "7"]
[White "Granda Zuniga Julio E PER"]
[Black "Seirawan, Yasser"]
[Result "1-0"]
[BlackElo "2595"]
[ECO "A30h"]
[NIC "EO 40.6.2"]

1.Nf3 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.Nc3 e6 4.g3 b6 5.Bg2 Bb7 6.O-O Nc6 7.e4 e5 8.d3 g6 9.Nxe5 Nxe5 10.f4 Nc6 11.e5 Ng8 12.f5 Nh6 13.Ne4 Nxf5 14.Nf6+ Ke7 15.Nd5+ Ke8 16.Nf6+ Ke7 17.g4 Nfd4 18.Qe1 Qb8 19.Nd5+ Kd8 20.Bg5+ Kc8 21.Rxf7 Ne6 22.Bf6 Ncd8 23.Re7 Rg8 24.Re8 Bc6 25.Bxd8 Nxd8 26.Nf6 Rh8 27.Bxc6 dxc6 28.Qe4 Qc7 29.e6 Bg7 30.e7 Rxe8 31.Nxe8 Bd4+ 32.Kh1 Qd7 33.Nd6+ Qxd6 34.e8=Q a5 35.Rf1 Ra7 36.Rf8 Rd7 37.Q4e6 Qxe6 38.Qxe6 Kc7 39.Qe2 Bg7 40.Rf2 Bd4 41.Rf3 Nf7 42.Rf4 Nd6 43.Kg2 Nc8 44.b3 Re7 45.Re4 Rf7 46.Qe1 Rd7 47.Qg3+ Kb7 48.Re6 Bc3 49.Qf3 Nd6 50.Qf8 Nc8 51.Re8 Rc7 52.Rd8 Bg7 53.Qe8 Bf6 54.Rxc8 1-0
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one.